# Pulling specific data from php file

Tags: php

Essentially, I have pulled the text from a URL and need to find a way to pull specific characters from the text.

The line I need pulled from is:

```
<p align="center"><a href="http://sitexplosion.com/?rid=1256" target="_blank">http://sitexplosion.com/?rid=1256</a></p>
```

The text I need pulled is essentially the number 1256, basically everything after ?rid= and before " target="_blank">

That number will change and will be anywhere from 1 to 6 characters in length.

If something like this has been posted already, I apologize. I have been scouring the net for the last 3 hours trying to find an answer of some sort.

If you can show me how to pull those characters from that line, I have got the rest already going.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $_GET['rid'] will do this for you ?

Comment: I think you need to pull that info from string, so for that you need preg_match

Comment: from what I understand, to use preg_match, I would need to know the characters I am looking for, which I don't. I only know what is before and after those characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this one:-

```
$strout="<p align='center'><a href='http://sitexplosion.com/?rid=1256' target='_blank'>http://sitexplosion.com/?rid=1256</a></p>";
$startsAt = strpos($strout, "?rid") + strlen("?rid=");
$endsAt = strpos($strout, "{\'target}", $startsAt);
$result = substr($strout, $startsAt, ($endsAt-3) - $startsAt);
echo $result;
```

Output:-

[image]

Comment: to use the $_GET, that information needs to be displayed in the URL. The code I have is just a specific line from a .php file. Unless I am wrong or missing something...

Answer (score 1):

Here, why not use a HTML parser or domdocument to extract the links, then get the links query params with parse_url()

```
$html = '
<p align="center"><a href="http://sitexplosion.com/?rid=1256" target="_blank">http://sitexplosion.com/?rid=1256</a></p>
<p align="center"><a href="http://sitexplosion.com/?rid=123456" target="_blank">http://sitexplosion.com/?rid=123456</a></p>
<p align="center"><a href="http://sitexplosion.com/" target="_blank">http://sitexplosion.com/</a></p>
';

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$link_ids = array();
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link)
{
    if($query = parse_url($link->getAttribute('href'), PHP_URL_QUERY))
    {
        $link_ids[] = str_replace('rid=','',$query);
    }
}

print_r($link_ids);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => 1256
    [1] => 123456
)
*/
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Well this is much shorter

```
$string = strip_tags('<p align="center"><a href="http://sitexplosion.com/?rid=1256" target="_blank">http://sitexplosion.com/?rid=1256</a></p>');

echo str_replace('http://sitexplosion.com/?rid=','',$string);
```